GCP - Query error: Correlated subqueries - BigQuery Limitations in UDF
I'm trying to create a function in BigQuery which uses some of our business logic / calculations. but more importantly there is a table which is regular updated by our staff.
this table contains dates for the years, and other specific values, but in this case "Holiday_Flag".
the purpose of this function is that in many of our reporting procedures they will use 2 date columns, again, containing many CTE's etc followed by this function to give us the total delay from a job starting and ending, in hours.
I've tried many different ways, even tried using ARRAY_AGG and UNNEST native to BiGQuery, to no avail.
when I completely remove this reference to another table out of the function, and hard code some dummy dates in, it works.
I have tried some help from the GPT AL world, but all get the same error.
here is the latest code I tried, I'm quite new to BigQuery and only found out about the UDF limitation recently. I do understand that its not efficient getting a function to perform a calculation on a million row table, and referring to the source table a million times.
I'm running out of time, and need some steer, I even got this working when I hard coded some dummy dates and a flag into a CTE, but using a lookup table fails
here is the code where.
staff_time uses: cal_date is just yyyy-mm-dd and holiday_flag is just "Y" or "N"
        CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION `my.gcp.function`(ip_start_date TIMESTAMP, ip_end_date TIMESTAMP) RETURNS NUMERIC AS (
(
WITH temp_date AS (
    SELECT
        CASE
            WHEN ip_start_date > ip_end_date THEN DATE(ip_end_date)
            ELSE DATE(ip_start_date)
        END AS ip_date_01,
        CASE
            WHEN ip_start_date > ip_end_date THEN DATE(ip_start_date)
            ELSE DATE(ip_end_date)
        END AS ip_date_02
),
validated_dates AS (
    SELECT
        ip_start_date,
        ip_end_date,
        CASE
            WHEN SAFE_CAST(ip_start_date AS DATE) IS NULL THEN 'Invalid start date format'
            WHEN SAFE_CAST(ip_end_date AS DATE) IS NULL THEN 'Invalid end date format'
            ELSE 'Valid dates'
        END AS date_validation
    FROM
        temp_date
),
holiday_array AS (
    SELECT
        ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(DATE(cal_date) AS cal_date, holiday_flag)) AS holidays
    FROM
        `dataset.staff_time`
),
working_days AS (
    SELECT
        CASE
            WHEN DATE(ip_start_date) <> DATE(ip_end_date) THEN SUM(
                CASE
                    WHEN cal_date NOT IN (
                        SELECT
                            cal_date
                        FROM
                            UNNEST(
                                (
                                    SELECT
                                        holidays
                                    FROM
                                        holiday_array
                                )
                            )
                        WHERE
                            holiday_flag = 'Y'
                    )
                    AND EXTRACT(
                        DAYOFWEEK
                        FROM
                            cal_date
                    ) NOT IN (1, 7) THEN 1
                    ELSE 0
                END
            ) - 1 --as we are now working in arrays, this is zero based counting
            ELSE NULL
        END AS working_day,
        ip_start_date,
        ip_end_date
    FROM
        UNNEST(
            GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY(
                SAFE_CAST(ip_start_date AS DATE),
                DATE_SUB(SAFE_CAST(ip_end_date AS DATE), INTERVAL 1 DAY),
                INTERVAL 1 DAY
            )
        ) AS cal_date
    WHERE
        cal_date NOT IN (
            SELECT
                cal_date
            FROM
                UNNEST(
                    (
                        SELECT
                            holidays
                        FROM
                            holiday_array
                    )
                )
            WHERE
                holiday_flag = 'Y'
        )
        AND EXTRACT(
            DAYOFWEEK
            FROM
                cal_date
        ) NOT IN (1, 7)
),
start_date AS (
    SELECT
        CASE
            WHEN DATE(ip_start_date) NOT IN (
                SELECT
                    cal_date
                FROM
                    UNNEST(
                        (
                            SELECT
                                holidays
                            FROM
                                holiday_array
                        )
                    )
                WHERE
                    holiday_flag = 'Y'
            )
            AND EXTRACT(
                DAYOFWEEK
                FROM
                    DATE(ip_start_date)
            ) NOT IN (1, 7) THEN ip_start_date
            ELSE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()
        END AS ip_start_date_1
),
end_date AS (
    SELECT
        CASE
            WHEN DATE(ip_end_date) NOT IN (
                SELECT
                    cal_date
                FROM
                    UNNEST(
                        (
                            SELECT
                                holidays
                            FROM
                                holiday_array
                        )
                    )
                WHERE
                    holiday_flag = 'Y'
            )
            AND EXTRACT(
                DAYOFWEEK
                FROM
                    DATE(ip_end_date)
            ) NOT IN (1, 7) THEN ip_end_date
            ELSE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()
        END AS ip_end_date_1
),
start_working_hours AS (
    SELECT
        CASE
            WHEN DATE(ip_end_date) <> DATE(ip_end_date) THEN CASE
                WHEN DATE(ip_start_date_1) <> DATE(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()) THEN 17 - ROUND(
                    EXTRACT(
                        HOUR
                        FROM
                            ip_start_date_1
                    ) + (
                        EXTRACT(
                            MINUTE
                            FROM
                                ip_start_date_1
                        ) / 60
                    ),
                    2
                )
                ELSE 0
            END
        END AS start_working_hour
    FROM
        start_date
),
end_working_hours AS (
    SELECT
        CASE
            WHEN DATE(ip_start_date) <> DATE(ip_end_date) THEN CASE
                WHEN DATE(ip_end_date_1) <> DATE(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()) THEN ROUND(
                    EXTRACT(
                        HOUR
                        FROM
                            ip_end_date_1
                    ) + EXTRACT(
                        MINUTE
                        FROM
                            ip_end_date_1
                    ) / 60 - 8,
                    2
                )
                ELSE 0
            END
        END AS end_working_hour
    FROM
        end_date
),
when_delay_on_same_day1 AS (
    SELECT
        CASE
            WHEN DATE(ip_start_date) = DATE(ip_end_date) THEN CASE
                WHEN DATE(ip_start_date) NOT IN (
                    SELECT
                        cal_date
                    FROM
                        UNNEST(
                            (
                                SELECT
                                    holidays
                                FROM
                                    holiday_array
                            )
                        )
                    WHERE
                        holiday_flag = 'Y'
                )
                AND EXTRACT(
                    DAYOFWEEK
                    FROM
                        DATE(ip_start_date)
                ) NOT IN (1, 7) THEN ROUND(
                    ABS(TIMESTAMP_DIFF(ip_end_date, ip_start_date, SECOND)) / 10000,
                    3
                )
                ELSE NULL
            END
            ELSE NULL
        END AS when_delay_on_same_day
)
SELECT
    CAST(
        IFNULL(start_working_hour, 0) + IFNULL(end_working_hour, 0) + IFNULL(working_day, 0) * 9 + IFNULL(when_delay_on_same_day, 0) AS NUMERIC
    ) AS final_working_hour
FROM
    start_working_hours,
    end_working_hours,
    working_days,
    when_delay_on_same_day1,
    start_date,
    end_date
)
);

I have tried using a join on the working_days CTE but still no joy.
working_days AS (
    SELECT
        CASE
            WHEN DATE(ip_start_date) <> DATE(ip_end_date) THEN SUM(
                CASE
                    WHEN ot.cal_date IS NULL 
                    AND EXTRACT(DAYOFWEEK FROM cal_date) NOT IN (1, 7) THEN 1
                    ELSE 0
                END
            ) - 1 -- Adjusting for zero-based counting
            ELSE NULL
        END AS working_day,
        ip_start_date,
        ip_end_date
    FROM
        UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY(SAFE_CAST(ip_start_date AS DATE), DATE_SUB(SAFE_CAST(ip_end_date AS DATE), INTERVAL 1 DAY), INTERVAL 1 DAY)) AS cal_date
    LEFT JOIN holiday_array ot
    ON cal_date = ot.cal_date -- Both are now DATE types
    WHERE ot.cal_date IS NULL
    AND EXTRACT(DAYOFWEEK FROM cal_date) NOT IN (1, 7)
),

Help will be very much appreciated

Your example generates for each entry all dates the project was running. This generates a huge load. Then you join the holidays to this data. A better solution would be to just join the holiday data directly to your dataset and count them. For calculating the weekdays the project is running a function without unnesting data can be used.

I understand, and i tried the join initially before going down the array route, but i got the same error. i Must be missing something as a lot of help texts say to do an efficient join, the only thing i can join on is a date

In this SQL example only the holiday dates are joined to the table. Even for 1 million row this can be done in 3 minutes. When the start and end dates are mixed, please fix this in an extra CTE. The CTE holiday_tbl contains a table of all holiday dates which are not on weekends. The CTE tbl1 counts to holiday in range. The CTE tbl2 shifts start and end date to the next Monday or previous Friday afternoon. The tbl3 calculates the working_days Monday and Friday in the selected time range without considering holidays. start_minutes and end_minutes are the minutes on the first and last day of the given time range. Some fixes are made so that only positiv time is added and a maximum of 9 hours.
The working hours are 9 per day and we need to substract the holidays from working days and also one day more because we ignore starting and end date here : 9*(working_days-1-holidays) . If the first day is a holiday, then we would substract a day from the calulation. This would be wrong, because the first day is not counted at working day. To fix that we add 9 hours. If the first day is not a holiday we add the hours worked on it ('start_minutes/60'). The same we do for the last day.
A remark for the working_days. The task is to find the weekend. Therefore, we search for the previous Monday by date_trunc(date(start_),ISOWEEK). The week difference to the final date are the weekends. Because we trunc our dates the weekdays, the weekends times two needs to be substracted from the date differnce to obtain the weekdays in that time range.
create temp function working_hours(start TIMESTAMP,ending TIMESTAMP)  as ((
  WITH
  holiday_tbl as (SELECT cal_date from Test.staff_time where holiday_flag='Y' and EXTRACT(DAYOFWEEK FROM cal_date) NOT in (1,7) ),
  tbl1 as (
SELECT count(cal_date) as holidays,
  ifnull(max(cal_date=date(start)),false) as start_on_holiday,
  ifnull(max(cal_date=date(ending)),false) as ending_on_holiday 
  from  holiday_tbl 
  Where date(cal_date) between date(start) and date(ending)
  ),
  tbl2 as (
  Select  *,
    Case EXTRACT(DAYOFWEEK FROM start) when 1 then timestamp_add(timestamp(date(start)+1),interval 17 hour) # Sunday is off, plus one day is Monday
      when 7 then timestamp(date(start)+2) # Saturday is off, plus two days is Monday
      else start end as start_,
    Case EXTRACT(DAYOFWEEK FROM ending) when 1 then timestamp_add(timestamp(date(ending)-2),interval 17 hour) # Sunday is off,minus two day is Friday
      when 7 then timestamp_add(timestamp(date(ending)-1),interval 17 hour) # Saturday is off, minus one day is Friday
      else ending end as ending_,
  from tbl1),
  tbl3 as (
  Select *,date_diff(date(ending_),date(start_),day) - 2*  date_diff(date(ending_),date_trunc(date(start_),ISOWEEK), week) as working_days,
   least(greatest(time_diff(time("2000-01-01 17:00:00 UTC"), time(start_), minute),0),9*60) as start_minutes,
   least(greatest(time_diff(time(ending_),time("2000-01-01 8:00:00 UTC"), minute),0),9*60) as ending_minutes,
  from tbl2
  )
  Select struct( 9*(working_days-1-holidays) + if(start_on_holiday, +9, start_minutes/60 ) + if(ending_on_holiday, +9, ending_minutes/60 ) as working_hours,
  holidays,start_on_holiday,ending_on_holiday,start_,ending_,working_days,start_minutes,ending_minutes)
  
  from tbl3
  
));

with test as ( Select timestamp("2023-01-05 12:55:00 UTC") as start ,timestamp("2023-01-07 14:55:00 UTC") as ending union all SELECT timestamp("2023-01-05 12:55:00 UTC") as start ,timestamp("2023-02-07 14:55:00 UTC") union all SELECT timestamp("2023-01-01 12:55:00 UTC") as start ,timestamp("2023-02-07 14:55:00 UTC")

union all Select timestamp("2023-01-04 14:00:00 UTC"),timestamp("2023-01-04 16:00:00 UTC")
 ),
test2 as (SELECT id, timestamp_sub(current_timestamp(),INTERVAL CAST((rand()*100-5)*3600*24 as int64) second)start ,timestamp_sub(current_timestamp(),INTERVAL CAST((rand()*100-10)*3600*24 as int64) second) ending from unnest(generate_array(1,1000*1000)) as id)

SELECT *,
working_hours(start,ending)

from test


basically the table which is a holiday flag which indicates UK bank holidays from 2016 to as far as 2026.
